# update manager won't work in 12.04

Tags: updates

I click on "install updates" and get a window;-

Another application seems to be 
using the package system at this 
time. You must close all other 
package managers before you 
will be able to install or 
remove any packages.

As far as I can see no other applications are running (I've just booted)

I've tried "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" suggested by JoKeR. This appears to work, but I get left with a EULA window which I can't get rid of except by closing the console window. This doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: just open system monitor via Dash and just check if any is running in the background if so terminate the process. In other side you can run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` via terminal should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is an similar question here on ask ubuntu, you can try using the answers there [muon package manager thinks that other package manager is open, and is not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87916/muon-package-manager-thinks-that-other-package-manager-is-open-and-is-not)